# Exact Target Automation Studio: Create multiple automation instances listening to same folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, csv, import, automation

We use Exact Target for marketing emails. In ET cloud, we have several attributes (columns), and we want to populate different attributes at different frequency and using different csv import files. Following is our setup for one of the CSV import files.

1. Import activity is set up to look for that file in /Imports directory.
2. Automation job is set up to call the import activity when a new file is created in /Imports directory.

Now, we want to setup another automation job that listens to /Imports directory for new file creations, but import activity for that job will be different. But, the UI is not allowing us to do so.

What are our options? Can we create different directories in FTP root?

Thanks,

Rishi

Answer (score 1):

I have set up custom File Locations under Admin for several directories under the Import folder and then configure Triggered Automations to watch each of them.  All you need is to configure full path to the ET Import folder as an external SFTP site like this:

[image: ftp-location-configuration-example]

Comment: Ill have to try this. I've never gotten this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, i see what you are doing. You've set it up as an external site. I dont think it works when you use enhanced ftp. Never thought to use the EFTP account as an external. Seems obvious now.

Comment: I think I've been trying to get the subdirectory from the import file name, and not specifying the location like this. Good call.

Comment: Triggered Automations are one of my new favorite things in the platform.  Been using the heck out of them for campaigns and chunked-up large data imports.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one folder available in the Exacttarget Enhanced FTP.  You would want to use personalization strings like this `subscribers%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%.csv`

More information regarding imports is [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/).

The `File Location` can also be an external source, but you can't specify directories there - you would need to create logins that are chroot'd to the specific folder and use different login information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, ideally I would want to create about 10 automation jobs that would listen to 10 different directories inside Imports directory. All those 10 automation jobs will execute 10 different import activities. What I can do is create directory inside imports directory, and create an automation to listen to that directory. But, I cannot create an import activity that imports from a file from a specific subdirectory. Thats odd very odd.

Comment: Yes,  totally agree.  This isn't something supported by the app.you would need separate ftplocations and users that point to those folders. Or develop a making convention that works.

Comment: You can specify sub-directories.