# SFTP connection from salesforce to Globalscape

Tags: integration, jitterbit, automationstudio

I need to connect my salesforce instance to Globalscape(file transfer suite) using a SFTP conncetion to extract a flat file.

I am looking for a freeware so that I could automate the same through a batch process.
Can anyone tell me what are my options?
Jitterbit/Filezilla

Since this will be used for marketing cloud solutions , is automation studio a viable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Automation Studio for it. The approach is described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31699/exact-target-automation-studio-create-multiple-automation-instances-listening-t).

The key steps are

1) Create a File Transfer Activity

2) Create Import Activity

3) Create "Import Action Settings” and “Import Completion Settings”

4) Create Automation using Automation Studio

There're other 3rd party tools as well e.g. - [Put It Forward](https://www.putitforward.com/) provides a Free tier which should serve your requirements well enough and

Comment: Thanks Gaurav!!
So Jitterbit won't work in this case?

Comment: I believe that should work as well going by the doumentation - https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/Creating+an+FTP+Source However, I've never used it for that purpose.